# What is the best way to dynamically evaluate multiple function?

Tags: functions, dynamic

I have a notebook with a list of operation where the result of a function is the input of the following.

Example:

```
a = DoSomething1[OriginalInput];
b = DoSomething2[a];
c = DoSomething3[b];
ShowData[c]
```

If I want to dynamically update the data I can use the "Dynamic" function like this:

```
Dynamic[
   ShowData[DoSomething3[DoSomething2[DoSomething1[OriginaInput]]]]
]
```

But this is very inconvenient. Probably I can use Function

```
a[Input_]:=DoSomething1[Input];
[...]
ShowData[c[b[a[CurrentInput]]]
```

But again it's quite similar.

**Is there a better way to achieve the dynamic evaluation of a series of Function?**

*Extra: my program Use CurrentImage[] as input and then apply some image transformation based on the position of several elements in the picture*

Comment: `foo[x_]:= c @ b @ a @ x; Dynamic[foo @ input]`?

Comment: thanks @Kuba for your comment. in you example a, b, c are function name like a[input_]:=DoSomething1[input]?

Comment: yep, does it fit your needs? p.s. look out for single capital letters because many have built-in meaning. `C, D, K, I, E, O` for example.

Comment: Or `foo = Composition[c, b, a]` (equivalently, `foo = c@*b@*a`). -- But frankly, I don't see what's inconvenient about your two proposed solutions.

Comment: It works! Thank you @Kuba ! But if I have one of my function (eg: b) that needs more than one parameter, is it possible to use the same approach? (not for this case, but as a general question) p.s. Capital letters were just an example, but you are right!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just wrap Dynamic around the whole thing if you want:

```
Dynamic[
  a = DoSomething1[input];
  b = DoSomething2[a];
  c = DoSomething3[b];
  ShowData[c],
  TrackedSymbols :> {input}
]
```

By using the `TrackedSymbols` option, the whole thing will only update if the variable `input` changes (if you don't specify this option, it may update many more times than necessary).

Note, however, that the evaluation will only take place whenever the `Dynamic` expression is being displayed. If it's hidden in some way or another, it may not update. This may not matter if you're only interesting in seeing the result of `ShowData[c]`. On the other hand, if you rely on `a`, `b` and `c` to be up-to-date with the variable `input`, you may run into problems if the dynamic expression is not currently on-screen.

Furthermore, it the computations take a significant amount of time, it's recommended to use the `SynchronousUpdating -> False` option for `Dynamic`, otherwise your notebook will freeze constantly (and the computation may even time out).

Finally, you may want to localize the intermediate variables `a`, `b` and `c` with a scoping construct (`DynamicModule`, `Module` or `Block`), depending on what you're doing. For example:

```
Dynamic[ Module[{a, b, c},
   a = DoSomething1[input];
   b = DoSomething2[a];
   c = DoSomething3[b];
   ShowData[c]
  ],
  TrackedSymbols :> {input}
]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for! TrackedSymbols and SynchronousUpdating are very useful. Thank you @Sjoerd Smit